# Read textfile (stored in Project) to string in ASP MVC (DNX CORE)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dnx

I have a DNX class library project in my ASP.NET MVC Project under DNX Core. In this class library I want to implement classic HTMLHelper Functions that return a string after some HTML manipulations. (No TagHelper at the moment.)

In the sense of a simple template approach I would like to first read a HTML template from a txt or html file that is stored within the project (just to make formatting, etc. more simple) to a string variable, do some string manipulations and then return the string.

I started to develop a traditional System.IO approach but recognized that it is not part of DNX Core so far. I wonder if there is a better way to access a Textfile stored within the project and read it as a string. IHostingEnvironment for instance?

Happy for any suggestions.

Regards

Marco

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a look at [this](https://github.com/aspnet/dnx/issues/3226) issue? Looking at the [reverse package website](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/) there are alternatives for System.IO.

**Example**

*Program.cs*

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
   public class Program
   {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         string content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("MyTextFile.txt");

 #if DNX451
         Console.WriteLine("NET451");
 #elif DNXCORE50
         Console.WriteLine("DNXCORE50");
 #endif

         Console.WriteLine(content);
         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

*project.json*

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "description": "ConsoleApp1 Console Application",
  "compilationOptions": {
     "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "commands": {
  "ConsoleApp1": "ConsoleApp1"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": { },
    "dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-23516",
        "System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.1-beta-23516"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Use [dnvm](http://www.sblackler.net/2015/05/02/Up-And-Running-With-DNX-DNVM-DNU/) to install and select the default framework and use *dnu restore* to ensure all packages are restored. Execution of *dnx run* from the project directory wil start the program.

```
dnvm list
dnu restore
dnvm upgrade -r clr -arch x64
dnx run
dnvm upgrade -r coreclr -arch x64
dnx run
```

Comment: I tried this by installing System.IO 4.0.11-beta-23516 via nuget and used `StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");` in my function but still get compiling error: 1) converting from string to System.IO not possible. Do you know how to refernece the file?

Comment: I also tried to add further dependent libs such as System.IO.Filesystem via nuget but build process says that dependency does not support NET Framework 4.5.1